# In Eclipse, how to register a type of the markers produced from a specific user-defined Java annotation processor

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-jdt, annotation-processing

I have followed this [tutorial](http://kerebus.com/2011/02/using-java-6-processors-in-eclipse/) and successfully created my own Java annotation processor for Eclipse.

The message, `"This is an error."`, I passed into the method call `processEnv.getMessager().printMessage(Kind.ERROR, "This is an error", element)` in the processor was successfully made appeared as a marker in the editor where the annotated element is.

Now I want to make a quick fix plug-in corresponding to that marker. **Which type of the marker should I use to register in `<handledMarkerTypes>` in the `plugin.xml` so that the plug-in handles only the marker originated from my annotation processor?**